# Why does using `execl` instead of `system` stops my program from working?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, ipc

I'm trying to do basic IPC using pipes. I spent hours searching the internet, doing this and that, reading the API documentations, and ended up with the code below. But it does not work, as I quite expected. Just any help making my code 'work' would be many thanks.

<edit>
I've just found that using `system` instead of `execl` makes my program run perfectly as expected. So what is going wrong here when I use `execl`, while it doesn't happen with the `system` function?
</edit>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int hInPipe[2];
    int hOutPipe[2];
    FILE *hInFile;
    FILE *hOutFile;
    char *s;

    pipe(hInPipe);
    pipe(hOutPipe);
    if(fork()){
        close(hInPipe[0]);
        close(hOutPipe[1]);
        hInFile=fdopen(hInPipe[1],"w");
        fprintf(hInFile,"2^100\n");
        fclose(hInFile);
        hOutFile=fdopen(hOutPipe[0],"r");
        fscanf(hOutFile,"%ms",&s);
        fclose(hOutFile);
        printf("%s\n",s);
        free(s);
    }else{
        dup2(hInPipe[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(hOutPipe[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(hInPipe[0]);
        close(hInPipe[1]);
        close(hOutPipe[0]);
        close(hOutPipe[1]);

        system("bc -q");/*this works*/
        /*execl("bc","-q",NULL);*/ /*but this doesn't*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplify the problem.  Replace `bc` with `cat`, replace `fscanf` with `read`.  And add error checking.

Comment: Also, don't write into an uninitialized pointer, or free it.

Comment: What does "it does not work, as I quite expected" mean?  What actually happens?  What did you expect?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did write a lot of C, but I have nearly 0 experience in this kind of programming, interacting with the OS deeply. The sample code I tried is really almost everything I need to achieve now. With hours of a mess, I think I got 98% right, but the computer isn't very tolerable with the last 2% miss. I just need a small tweak that will complete my solution.

Comment: @WilliamPursell So which part of my program is going wrong? The fscanf line there seems okay to me. I used `%ms` instead of `%s`, so there is no writing into an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Although we appreciate your great faith in our analytical skills, it is difficult to determine what is wrong with your program when you don't describe the observed misbehavior.  I repeat: What actually happens? What did you expect?

Comment: You should definitely be handling those return values, one of those many function calls could be failing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I found the problem more narrowly. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the fine man page. :)

```
execl(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);
```

`arg0` (aka argv[0], the name the program is told it was invoked under) is **not** the same argument as the path (the location of the executable for said program). Moreover, `execl` takes, as its first argument, a fully-qualified pathname.

Thus, you want:

```
execl("/usr/bin/bc", "bc", "-q", NULL);
```

...or, to search the PATH for `bc` rather than hardcoding a location:

```
execlp("bc", "bc", "-q", NULL);
```